# more then one CCScrollLayer

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccscrolllayer

I have two CCScrollLayers in one scene (implementation) in an Xcode iPhone project with cocos2d.

It only works with the last created scrollayer. Why? How can it be done to work with both?

Not working = looks like static object with no interation = no scrolling at all, BUT pages are actually created and I see them.

Comment: It's all happening just because some layer steals your touches..

Comment: @mayoxy: how can you fix the problem? Could you share your solution? I got the same one in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the latest version? 0.2.0. 
There was a fix described as:  9. Ability to disable stealing touches (stealTouches property).
Maybe setting that will solve your problems.

If it doesn't, can't you just do with regular UIKit scroll views? If you are using them on menus or not intensive screens you shouldn't run into much trouble.